# Pass Options to Google Charts from jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, google-visualization

I am trying to automate the creation of a chart (using the Google Charts API), by using jQuery to call a PHP page. I am returning JSON for the data and, currently, am just returning a string for the options.

The chart 'data' works fine, but I am having difficulty passing the 'options' automatically. A snippet of my code is below:

```
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "http://server.com/charts/dev/data.php",
        dataType:"json",
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    var optionData = $.ajax({
        url: "http://server.com/charts/dev/options.php",
        dataType:"text",
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, optionData);
```

If I remove the jQuery that tries to get 'optionData', and just supply it myself, the chart loads. Otherwise, I get 'Cannot read property '0' of null' appearing as an error (nothing on the Console).

The PHP page 'options.php' looks like this (for now):

```
<?php
echo <<< 'EOT'
{width: 400, height: 240}
EOT;
```

If I add in Console.Log(optionData), I get `{width: 400, height: 240}` as expected.

Comment: What is the difference between the data when you supply it and the data as it appears when you console.log it? The ajax request returns `'{width: 400, height: 240}'` is that precisely the same when you provide the data and console.log it?

Comment: @Stuart it appears to be exactly the same `{width: 400, height: 240}`. Is there some easy way I can find out the type of the object that's being returned?

Comment: Yes, you can use `typeof`. Example `console.log(typeof optionData)` You should also check to see what you have for `data` and `chart` to make sure they are getting created properly.

Comment: One thing to consider, your ajax specifies `string` but are you certain you need a string? What you output looks like an object, not a string.

Comment: @Stuart they're both strings according to typeof. If I specify the data manually, it becomes an object. Any idea how I could get the output to be an object?

`var optionData = $.ajax({
                url: "http://server.com/charts/dev/options.php",
                async: false
            }).responseText;

            console.log(typeof jsonData);
            console.log(typeof optionData);

            var optionData = {width: 400, height: 240};
            console.log(typeof optionData);`

This logs:
`string
string
object`

Comment: Setting the ajax request to `datatype: json` will return an object (or an error if it cannot parse as such).

Comment: You should try json encoding your PHP, see my amended answer below.

Comment: @Stuart I have tried setting the dataType to JSON, it still returns a string (see above). This works fine for the DataTable though. I've changed my PHP code to use json_encode, and have got it to identify itself as a json file in the header. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what I tried, the jQuery always seemed to return a string, rather than an object.

This was fine for 'google.visualization.DataTable', but 'google.visualization.AreaChart' required an object. I'm now using something like this, which works perfectly:

```
var optionData = jQuery.parseJSON($.ajax({
    url: "http://server.com/charts/release/getChartOptions.php",
    dataType:"json"
    async: false
}).responseText);
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you test to replace datatype of optiondata.

From:

```
    var optionData = $.ajax({
        url: "http://server.com/charts/dev/options.php",
        dataType:"text",
        async: false
    }).responseText;
```

to:

```
    var optionData = $.ajax({
        url: "http://server.com/charts/dev/options.php",
        dataType:"JSON",
        async: false
    }).responseText;
```

Comment: No difference unfortunately. I've also tried omitting dataType.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot ajax calls define the error, success and complete callbacks:

```
var optionData = $.ajax({
    url: "http://server.com/charts/dev/options.php",
    dataType:"json", // I think using 'text' here is wrong as `draw` expects objects
    async: false,
    error: function(xhr, status, err){
        console.log('Error: ' + xhr); // you can also output status and err if needed
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log('Success: ' + data);
    },
    complete: function(data){
        console.log('Complete: ' + data);
    }
}).responseText;
```

One more thing, to ensure that PHP is returning an object json encode it in the PHP:

```
echo json_encode($your_data);
```